# Why my webdriver automation in finding path have to recall each time I change of it?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, automation

Ok so I don't have really problem, but I don't want my code to look messy but it does make it messy because of this code.

`containers = driver.find_elements(by="xpath",value='//*[@id="table"]/tbody/tr')`

So basically I have a crud-app in my website and I'm trying to automate it with python...but the thing is that when I edit a certain item. I have to break the loop of the containers and recall it so that it will not accept the new update of a certain item.

Let say first this is the creating of Item.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import time
import random
import string

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = "C:/SeleniumDrives/chromedriver.exe"

def generate_random_string(length):
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    return result_str

# Create a webdriver object for Chrome and set the window size
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
driver.set_window_size(1200, 800)

# driver.get("https://web-automation-one.vercel.app")
driver.get("https://web-automation-jullemyth122.vercel.app")

# Here is the inputs and button clicks...
# driver.find_element(by="xpath",value='//*[@id="id"]').click()
crud_list = []


for i in range(0,50):
    random_number = random.randint(1,2000)
    random_string = generate_random_string(20)
        
    driver.find_element(by="xpath", value='//*[@id="id"]') \
        .send_keys(str(random_number))
    driver.find_element(by="xpath", value='//*[@id="name"]') \
        .send_keys(random_string)

    # Create button
    driver.find_element(by="xpath", value='/html/body/div/form/button[1]').click()
    # Read button to update and show the list of items
    driver.find_element(by="xpath", value='/html/body/div/form/button[2]').click()
```

Now for the second part is that I have constraints wherein if the last part of string have `["A","C","K","Y","L","Z","R","M"]` parts.

then it gonna re-edit what that part is in `containers` or in the `list of the website`.
and this is the code.

```
status = True
counter = 0
while status:
    containers = driver.find_elements(by="xpath",value='//*[@id="table"]/tbody/tr')
    for container in containers:
        counter = 0
        random_string = generate_random_string(20) 
        s = str(container.find_element(by="xpath",value="./td[2]").text)
        print(s)
        if s[-1] in ["A","C","K","Y","L","Z","R","M"]:
            # //*[@id="table"]/tbody/tr[1]/button[2]
            # //*[@id="table"]/tbody/tr[2]/button[2]
            counter += 1
            #Edit button in certain item to pass in inputs
         container.find_element(by="xpath",value="./button[2]").click()
            driver.find_element(by="xpath", value='//*[@id="name"]') \
                .clear()
            driver.find_element(by="xpath", value='//*[@id="name"]') \
                .send_keys(random_string)
            # Update button
            driver.find_element(by="xpath", value='/html/body/div/form/button[3]').click()
            time.sleep(2)
            break

        if s[-1] in ["D","N","Q","E","S","T"]:


         # Delete button   
         container.find_element(by="xpath",value="./button[1]").click()
            time.sleep(2)
            break

    if counter == 0:
        break
```

As you see I use `break` in each those `for loops` because the containers or the list in the website change...and if detects again another in one of `contraints`. It is gonna have an error at this line.

```
s = str(container.find_element(by="xpath",value="./td[2]").text)
```

Yes, my code is working because I break it. But can anyone explain me why I have to break and recall my container so that I can update some other items. Is that a behavior or something? Thank you for anyone who can explain.

I also tag a javascript cause this is a crud-app automation.

Comment: The DOM is probably updating on the "update" or "delete" click.  At that point you need to re-get the "containers" array.  All methods used on those array references will throw stale element exception.  (I'd also suggest a bool instead of that counter = 0 thing...)

Comment: @pcalkins ah I see so there is no way point to reduce this code because of that `stale` element?

Comment: react apps re-render every time state changes. so yeah, look it up each time

Comment: @pguardiario nah its not react its normal javascript.

Comment: I figured it was because of vercel but maybe not